# I got an error `to_s': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) and How can i imrpove my "code"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Converting_numbers
  def con

    print "Enter decimal number to convert: "
    x = gets.chomp

    print <<-EOF
    1. Binary
    2. Eight
    3. Hexadecimal
    EOF

    print "Choose the notation to convert: "
    sys = gets.chomp.to_s

    if "1" === sys
      puts x = x.to_s(2)
    elsif "2" === sys
      puts x = x.to_s(8)
    elsif "3" === sys
      puts x = x.to_s(16)
    else
      puts "Wrong input! "  
    end 

  end
end

number = Converting_numbers.new
number.con
```

Why did a have such an error? Can somebody explain? 
What i need to change in my code to make it better? 
Should i use case? Or something else inspite of 'if'?
Thanks.

Comment: You apparently provided an argument to a method that doesn't require one.

Comment: `to_s` converts iE an `Integer` to a `String`. You don't have to pass a parameter (2, 8, 16) to it. What did you want to achieve with that?

Comment: convert a decimal number to binary number or other

Comment: @davegson: `Integer#to_s` *does* have one optional parameter, namely the base that the number should be represented in.

Comment: As @davegson indicates, `Integer#to_s` accepts an argument. However, you're applying `to_s` to a `String`. `String#to_s` does not accept any arguments. Try `x.to_i.to_s(8)` instead, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument you're passing to `to_s` is only available on an instance of `Integer`. However, since your input is a `String`, you first need to convert it to an `Integer`.

e.g. `x.to_i.to_s(2)`

Comment: Technically, `.to_i` isn't a *cast*, but a *conversion*. Cast does not generally imply conversion in a language.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `x = gets.chomp` is String.

And you try to convert it String again: `x.to_s(2)`.

But if you read [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:to_s), String's method `.to_s` hasn't any arguments and return self.

But Fixnum's method `.to_s` has argument. So you can [read it here](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Fixnum:to_s). And it converts number to selected system. Result is String.

In this way your code will work:

```
print "Enter decimal number to convert: "
x = gets.to_i
sys = nil

until (1..3).include?(sys)
  print "Select numeral system. 1. Binary. 2. Octal. 3. Hexadecimal. "
  sys = gets.to_i
end

if sys == 1
  y = x.to_s(2)
  s = "binary"
elsif sys == 2
  y = x.to_s(8)
  s = "octal"
else
  y = x.to_s(16)
  s = "hexadecimal"
end

puts "#{x} in #{s} system is #{y}."
```

By the way, your `sys = gets.chomp.to_s` isn't good idea, `sys = gets.chomp` is enough.

Hope, that helped you. And I voted up your question. I'm newbie too. But I think this site is to help other people, but not to vote down questions